# нужно, чтобы объект вращался пока не будет отпущена кнопка на UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Нужно, чтобы объект вращался пока не будет отпущена кнопка. Сейчас при нажатии копки задание выполняется только 1 раз.
код:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(10,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Замените `Input.GetKeyDown` на `Input.GetKey`